# How do i loop to scrape the id values of div tags using pythons bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a way to scrape the value of the 'data-block-id' for each of the div tags.

Im using BeautifulSoup and want loop through so i can store these values in a list and scrape data from within these tags when needed.

[image: html div tags]

Comment: please [edit] your question and insert the `HTML` source as a code instead of `img` so we can manually check and verify. also make sure your question is not a duplicated one, as your question is actually answered multiple times before. `data = [item.get("data-block-id") for item in soup.findAll("div", class_="DCMP_Block")]`

Answer (score 1):

```
data_block_ids = [div['data-block-id'] for div in soup.find_all('div', {'data-block-id': True})]
```

This is looking for all the divs with the attribute `data-block-id` and getting the value of the attribute from each div.

Comment: No worries! :-)